# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net

when i run in browser it gives error like Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions' or one of its dependencies.

I am using asp.net version 2.0.50727

Please give the solution.

Comment: Which .NET version are you running?

Comment: Add the reference for "System.Web" for the project using add reference...

Answer (score 1):

This is because you do not have install, or not include the Asp.Net Ajax. I am not sure what version are you use, but this is something that you know and you can get the appropriate files.

for example the version 1 is here.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=883